# How can we access private variables of a c# script from bolt visual script graph directly?

Tags: unity, c#, bolt-visual-scripting

As public variables are accessible from the bolt script and not private variables, is there a way to access them or we have to set the `set`s and `get`s as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. Variables get declared as `private` because they are not supposed to be changed from anywhere except from inside the class itself.

But if you really, really need to do this (again, you shouldn't), you could write [a custom Bolt node implemented by a C# class derived from `Unit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.visualscripting@1.7/manual/vs-creating-visual-script-graph-unit.html) with a method which accesses and changes a private variable on another object and then put *that* into your bolt graph. You can violate the privacy of a variable via [the C# reflection API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Some examples for how to perform this forbidden operation can be found in the answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection).
But again, **this is not a good idea**. When a variable is private and has no public getters or setters, then the author of that class likely had a reason for that.

Comment: I'd add here: if you yourself are the class author and are choosing `private` to avoid cluttering the inspector, you can use `[HideInInspector] public` to keep the variable hidden there while still exposing it to Bolt, without complicated reflection workarounds.